# ^$ Home page rewrite in htaccess not working, ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2.4, .htaccess

I am running `ubuntu 14.04` with `apache 2.4.x`. I created virtual host `mydomain.local`. All my website works perfectly on local machine except home page i.e. `http://mydomain.local/`

I can run anything like `http://mydomain.local/dir-name` or `http://mydomain.local/file.name`. In short all URLs are working fine which have something at tail.

Here is my directory structure:

```
/var/www/html/site_name/public
     .htaccess
     wp/index.php
     index.php
```

Following is my `.htaccess` code:

```
# Base is the URL path of the home directory
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ wp/index.php [L]

# Skip real files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise send it to WordPress
RewriteRule .* wp/index.php [L]
```

Virtualhost config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.local

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site_name/public

        <Directory /var/www/html/site_name/public>
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                Options +Indexes
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site_name_local_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site_name_local_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

All my URLs redirect to `/wp/index.php`. Only home `http://mydomain.local/` page is not rewriting.

**http://mydomain.local/ is not rendering main index.php instead of wp/index.php**

Note: Same code and htaccess configuration working on `ubuntu 16.04`.

Comment: What does the error and access logs show?

Comment: @vidarlo No error there. It loads main `index.php`. But according to rule it should render `wp/index.php`

Comment: @Parixit put in your current virtual host file `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6` and you will get logging ;) source http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: @Rinzwind Sure, I will put it and check.